# Rails4.1: AWS errors missing region

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create an image uploader using paperclip, the aws-sdk gem and Amazon S3.
I get this error:

```
Aws::Errors::MissingRegionError in ProjectsController#create. 
Missing region; use :region option or export region name to ENV['AWS_REGION']. using Oregon region.
```

**projects_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @project = current_user.projects.new(project_params)
    @project.save
    respond_with(@project)
end
```

**application.rb file**

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
        storage: :s3,
        s3_host_name: "s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
        s3_credentials: {
            bucket: ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
            access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
            secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
        }
    }
```

According to the S3 documentation I understand I need to change to ENV['AWS_REGION']

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
        storage: :s3,
            region: "ENV['AWS_REGION"],
        s3_credentials: {
            bucket: ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
            access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
            secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
        }
    }
```

and add region to my .env file

```
export AWS_BUCKET=realv1
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID_HERE>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<MY_ACCESS_KEY_HERE>
export AWS_REGION="'us-west-2'
```

I rebooted the server and retested but still get the same errors.

update

update:

in rails console

2.0.0p247 :001 > ENV["AWS_REGION"]

=> "us-west-2"
2.0.0p247 :002 >

Comment: Quotes near `AWS_REGION` are messed up.

Comment: That access key looks suspiciously legit :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error is originating from the Paperclip gem. In your `config.paperclip_defaults` you used `region` when you should have used `s3_region`. This is how the config should look:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_region => ENV['AWS_REGION'],
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Comment: I did this but didn't work. Does it need to be 'AWS_REGION', can't I simply have it called differently in my secrets or figaro .yml file?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your `.env` file which is most probably causing this error.

Change:

```
export AWS_REGION="'us-west-2'
```

to:

```
export AWS_REGION='us-west-2'
```

Reload the shell and try again.

#### Upate

Make sure your `ENV` hash has the correct `region`. You can check by typing: `ENV | grep AWS` in your console.

Then, add `region: ENV['AWS_REGION']` to your `s3_credentials`:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
        storage: :s3,
            region: ENV['AWS_REGION'],
        s3_credentials: {
            bucket: ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
            access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
            secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
        }
    }
```

Comment: You actually had another typo: `region: "ENV['AWS_REGION"],`
fix that and try again.

Comment: thanks for your help but getting the same error, using oregan which is 'us-west-2'

Comment: what happens if you out `region: ENV['AWS_REGION']` inside the `s3_credentials ` key?